# android kotlin network error - no network security config specified

Tags: android, networking, kotlin

i'm trying to connect to api by kotlin in android. but i'm getting error either

No network Securituy Config Specified, using platform default.

or

Using Network Security from resource ntwork_security_config debugBuild:true.

i already add network_security_config.xml in res/xml folder. can anyone help me with this problem?

below are some screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Neither of those are errors, they are just warnings letting you know which Security Config the app is using. Is your api call working or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your `network-security-config` should be similar as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">enter domain here</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Example:

If your network call sends request to this domain:

*www.myapp.com/api/something*

Then, your `network-security-config` will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.myapp.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this and remove android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" from the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this StrictMode Policy in onCreate of your class file..

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: still same :( . will it matter if i called api in fragment?

Comment: No it doesn't matter

Comment: still getting error using network security config from network_security_config debugBuild:true